# How to backup files without access to the desktop?

Tags: installation, backup

I recently made a driver change and now when I boot all I get is a black screen. I want to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 LTS without losing all of my data and files in my /home folder. How can I create a backup of my /home folder without access to my desktop? Note: I am able to access the GRUB menu but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Why not just remove the driver?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your stuff isn't encrypted, use either hirens boot cd and load mini xp, or use your install cd and click on "Try Ubuntu without installing". Then open up the file explorer and copy your stuff to another partition, another hard drive you have, or a usb flash drive. Re-install Ubuntu, and don't make a dangerous driver change ever again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Use Ubuntu Without Installing" from a USB drive or CD.
Once it boots use the File manager to backup your home directory into a different drive/External drive.

Then, install from the CD/USB, in all eventuality, the installer should detect an existing installation and prompt to "Upgrade" or "reinstall", you may even retain the folders depending on the options you choose.

Comment: I booted from a CD and selected "Use Ubuntu Without Installing". However my profile home directory is not there.